# Redis get function

Tags: javascript, caching, redis

I'm getting github repo data, and then i store it in redis with set. with get am getting current data, but when i trying add function to get it's not working.

```
let redisClient;

(async () => {
  redisClient = redis.createClient();

  redisClient.on("error", (error) => console.error(`Error : ${error}`));
  redisClient.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("Redis Connected!");
  });

  await redisClient.connect();
})();


// Make request to Github for data
async function getRepos(req, res, next) {
  try {
    console.log("Fetching Data...");

    const { username } = req.params;

    // with this am getting result
    const cacheResults = await redisClient.get(username);
    console.log(cacheResults);

    // with this am not getting result, how can i fix this? 
    redisClient.get(username, (err, data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    const repos = data.public_repos;

    // Set data to Redis
    redisClient.set(username, JSON.stringify(repos));

    res.send(setResponse(username, repos));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500);
  }
}
```

### it's don't console.log(data), i searched a lot and everyone have one example how to use get function, but in me case it's don't log, whats am doing wrong?

this is my cache function

```
// Cache middleware
async function cache(req, res, next) {
  const { username } = req.params;

  try {
    await redisClient.get(username).then((data) => {
      if (data !== null) {
        res.send(setResponse(username, data));
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.toString());
  }
}

app.get("/repos/:username", cache, getRepos);
```

it's works, but time finish times with cache and without it are same? am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try like this

```
redisClient.get(username).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot yes it's works now, i have one question, i edited my code can u see it please, catch time and without catch are same don't understand why

Comment: you can refer for cache in this post https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/simple-server-side-cache-for-express-js-with-node-js-45ff296ca0f0

Comment: thanks for resource, but i need to learn redis, and now i want to cache with it, it's works but why am getting same time in request don't understand lol )) thanks for response : )